# Scrolling is slower and laggy at the top and smoother at the rest of the page

Tags: android, android-layout, android-scrollview

I'm using ScrollView for scrolling in my page. But for some reason it is laggy and slower at the top of the page but when I scroll down it is smoother and faster. I don't understand why it behaves this way. You can see here is a video of what is happening:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1y9Q-JNFBGxHdKUkE_KRWCxfYqxRln7Vn/view?usp=sharing

It was all working just fine, I added four more CardsView and then this issue happened.
Here is a snippet of the code:

```
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/top"
    android:background="#F4F2F2"
    tools:context=".ui.home.HomeFragment">

    <GridLayout
        android:columnCount="2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/dog"
                android:layout_width="101dp"
                android:layout_height="61dp"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
                android:elevation="5dp"
                android:src="@drawable/dog" />


            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/d1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
                app:cardElevation="2dp"
                >
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/image_container1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">
                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/cave"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_gravity="top"
                        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                        android:maxHeight="400dp"
                        android:scaleType="fitXY"
                        android:src="@drawable/cave"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/myImageViewText"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignStart="@id/cave"
                        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/cave"
                        android:layout_alignTop="@id/cave"
                        android:layout_alignEnd="@id/cave"
                        android:layout_alignRight="@id/cave"
                        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/cave"
                        android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/arghavan"
                        android:textSize="20dp"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="@string/s1"
                        android:textColor="#000"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                </RelativeLayout>
            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
        </FrameLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            >
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/play"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:elevation="10dp"
                android:layout_gravity="top|center"
                android:src="@drawable/yonuswheal" />


            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/d2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
                app:cardElevation="2dp">
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/image_container"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/sea"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_gravity="top"
                        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                        android:maxHeight="400dp"
                        android:scaleType="fitXY"
                        android:src="@drawable/sea" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/myImageViewText2"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/sea"
                        android:layout_alignTop="@id/sea"
                        android:layout_alignRight="@id/sea"
                        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/sea"
                        android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/arghavan"
                        android:textSize="20dp"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="@string/s2"
                        android:textColor="#000"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
                </RelativeLayout>
            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
        </FrameLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Removed `android-studio` tag as that tag is for questions/issues with the Android Studio product. This question has nothing to do with Android Studio.